# Find the intersection between two convex hulls, in this specific case

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

We work over $\mathbb{R}^K$. Let $V$ be the set of vectors whose coordinates take values $0$ or $1$, or equivalently the corners of the unit cube $[0,1]^K$.

Let $d:\{0, \ldots, K\} \to \mathbb{R}_+$ be a function such that $d(k)$ decreases with $k$ (and the function $kd(k)$ increases with $k$).

We define the subset $S = \{d(\| \mathbf{v} \|_1)\mathbf{v}: \mathbf{v} \in V\}$. Let $C$ be its convex hull.

Let $S_1 = \{e \mathbf{v}: \| \mathbf{v} \|_1 =1;  (\mathbf{v}\in V) \}$, for some $e \in \mathbb{R}_+$.
We denote by $C_1$ the convex hull of $S_1$.

I need to find the intersection between $C$ and $C_1$ (we suppose that this intersection always exists). An illustration of an example in 2D is given by the following figure:

[image]

How to find the coordinates of the extremal points of the intersection of $C$ and $C_1$ in the general case? There are 2 such points in the above example.

Any hint is welcome.

Comment: I asked this question on [**mathexchange**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289520/find-the-intersection-between-two-convex-hulls-in-this-specific-case), but it didn't attract any attention.. PS: I don't know if this is the proper way to link the questions

Comment: It looks like the solution set is invariant under permutations of the indices.  It looks like it may be enough to consider finding l such that d(lhat) <e < d((l+1)hat), where hat of a number l has the first l coordinates 1 and the rest 0.  With l in hand, you can now consider linear combinations of the right number of vectors and do it up to permutation of coordinates.  Gerhard "Use Symmetry To Your Advantage" Paseman, 2015.05.20

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I am not sure I have understood your idea (and the notation). Could you please detail your answer?